# Writing spreadsheet to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to write a spreadsheet to Google Cloud Storage via App Engine Python.  I have code that worked with the Files API in the blobstore and initially tried to just switch out the storage backend using the (deprecated) GCS Files API, which has very similar code to that of the blobstore.  It kept giving me `UnknownError: ApplicationError: 7`, which is one issue.

But my bigger question is if it's possible to do this with the supported [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) since the Files API will be removed at some time in the future.  How do I write a spreadsheet (currently I'm using Python's `csv` module) to GCS with supported libraries?

Comment: i think this is the first time i've ever met somebody I knew irl by chance on the internet.  Hi, lol